# Creating common test data for multiple feature files

Tags: karate

My requirement is as follows:

1. I have a couple of .feature files. I want to create test data that would be common to all of these feature files. Once the test data is created the scenarios will be run from the feature files.
2. I also want some info back after the test data is created. eg., ids of the data that i have created. So i can use this info to call the api's, add in payloads in my scenarios.

I think we could do this by:
1. Creating a junit java file. I define a static method with @BeforeClass in there and use Karate's runner() to run my create-test-data.feature file (I can use Karate to hit application api to create some data). I define a property in my java class of type Object and set it with the result of Runner.runFeature().

2. Then I create a separate feature file test-data-details.feature. I define my Java Interop code here. eg.,

   - def test_data = 
     """
     var JavaOutput = Java.type('com.mycompany.JavaFile');
     var testData = JavaOutput.propertyName;
     """
3. Now that I have my test data object in my test-data-details.feature file. I call this .feature file (callonce) in the Background section of my feature files that have test scenarios in. So I can retries the test data details like id, name. etc that I can then use in the api request paths and payloads.

I am not sure if the above design is the correct way to go ahead. I tried but getting some issues in my Java file where getClass() below complains that it cannot be used in static method.

```
@RunWith(Karate.class)
```

public class AccountRunner {

```
public static Object job = null;

@BeforeClass
public static void create_job(){
    Map<String, Object> result = Runner.runFeature(getClass(), "test-data.feature", null, true);
    job = result.get("job");
}
```

}

Now all of the above can be totally wrong. Need help on how to tackle this scenario in Karate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have implemented the following design:

I have created two methods one with BeforeClass and other with AfterClass annotation in my TestRunner.java file. In these methods I am able to call the specific data creation and clean-up feature files and pass args as Json object.

```
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@KarateOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"})
public class AccountRunner {

    public static Map<String, Object> result = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void create_job() throws IOException, ParseException {

        Class clazz = AccountRunner.class;
        URL file_loc = clazz.getResource("create-test-data-1.json");

        File file = new File(file_loc.getFile());

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(file));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap();
        args.put("payload", jsonObject);

        result = Runner.runFeature(CommonFeatures.class, "create-data.feature", args, true);

    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void delete_investigation() {

        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap();
        args.put("payload", result);

        Runner.runFeature(CommonFeatures.class, "delete-job.feature", args, true);
    }


}
```

To run these tests via command line using "mvn test" command, i have done following changes in pom.xml.

```
           `<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`
```

With this solution I able to run my tests in IDE by executing the runner directly or by command line. However, I have not found a way to run all of my tests by following the karate suggested approach where I have a *Test.java file at test suite level and I use default maven configuration with "mvn test". The features fails to run as the .feature file is called before the Runner file is executed which has method to create test data for tests.

Maybe someone can suggest what else, I could do to use Karate approach of running *Test.java file instead of each *Runner.java file.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understand you have a common test data feature file, which you want to run before all the test and hold that response in a variable that can be used in all of the test features.

You can also achieve this in [karate-config.js](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-configjs) using [karate.callSingle()](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-callsingle)

In your `karate-config.js`

`config["testdata"] = karate.callSingle("test-data.feature")`

Your `test-data.feature` will be executed once before all the tests and store the response in `testdata` you can use this variable directly in your feature.

Comment: Ok this will work only for a specific set of feature files. My requirement is that i have sets of functionality that each has their own test data and for each set of functionality there are multiple feature files (organized by api's). This approach will make the config file too long i suppose with callSingle calls to each specific "test-data.feature". I there a way we could use the Java feature runner class to execute this and then all feature files use it?

Comment: Also,  i need to delete the test data (using a separate feature file) once all the feature files under a specific functionality (package) have been run. I think this can be achieved by calling the delete-data.feature in the @AfterClass method and using Karate Runner. Any guidance on how to get past the issue of calling the Runner.runFeature() in static method?

Comment: you can still go-ahead with above approach , instead of hard-coding feature file path in karate-config.js keep it in a json (`testdata.json`) with key as your test feature name and value as you testdata feature name. use `karate.info` to get current feature name in runtime and use that to extract the test data feature to run from your `testdata.json`. run and return in a variable as above. you don't have to delete , as everytime you are going to replace value on same varaible

Comment: I dont see any direct way to inject varaibles from `@BeforeTest` to you karate args. but you can write a utility to store that in json file and let your feature file read from that json.

Comment: I have created two methods one with BeforeClass and other with AfterClass annotation in my TestRunner.java file. In these methods I am able to call the specific data creation and clean-up feature files and pass args as Json object. This design works when i execute a test in my IDE by right clicking the TestRunner.java file. However, when i try to run tests using "mvn test", it fails as the BeforeClass method in my TestRunner.java is not executed and the feature files rely on that. Doesn't the TestRunner.java file gets executed before feature files are run?