# Why karate runner file is not run before running the feature files, when running Junit4 Test.java file for tests

Tags: karate

Karate suggests that to run all tests in a CI environment, a *Test.java file should be added above the feature files (in hierarchy) and then run using - mvn test command.
I am using my Runner.java file to create test data before the tests are run and then do a clean up. I run this runner file in IDE and everything runs fine - the data is created, all feature files in the same package run and then clean-up is performed. The reason i used the Runner file to create data is because i using karate itself to create test data and the Runner file passes some information on created data to the feature files to run api tests. I had earlier posted a question regarding how to achieve this, please refer to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931786/4741035

So now I have a *Test.java file in my project which i run using - mvn test. This runs all the feature files and tests fails as the Runner.java is not executed at all.

Why doesn't karate run the Runner file, if it is present first that the feature files?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you create a minimal running example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to run something "once" before all your tests, use `karate.callSingle()` documented here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

```
var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:demo/headers/common-noheaders.feature', config);
```

And in the above feature (or JS) you can call Java code using Java interop.

By the way I don't agree with the answer you linked because of the above approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What i am trying to understand is that if I use callSingle(), then from which feature file do i call it? When I have 5 feature files that reply on the same test data. How can i be sure that Karate will run the feature file that has callSingle() call before other dependant feature files are run?

Comment: @rochitsen you normally use `callSingle()` from the `karate-config.js` - please look at the examples and documentation. yes it is smart enough to run once for all features.

Comment: yes, i will look again into the callSingle() example. The reason I left that approach was becuase I couldnt figure out that even if I can use the config to run the callSingle once, i would also need to do a cleanup to delete the data after all those 5 feature files were run. There is an afterFeature hook, but that would work for each feature file whereas i want it to run after all feature files in a package are run. Thats why i wondering, why the Runner.java is not executed before the feature files are run using junit suggested run pattern.

Comment: @rochitsen see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55987985/143475 - so you can do something in the Java / JUnit runner before and after a parallel / suite run if you really want :) you seem to be confused with `Runner` and expecting it to be run automatically by maven in order - sorry, that's not how it works

Comment: thanks, it makes sense to use java in this specific requirement i have. So in my previous answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931786/4741035 i would put all that code in a FeaturesTest.java file and use Junit runner to run the Before() and After() methods and also use: *Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(),5)* to run the tests (all feature files in that package). This should work.